# Numeric Custom validation Message in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am writing the following code server side to validate if the role is selected or not ...

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'RoleID' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ];
}

public function messages() {
    return [
        'User.RoleID'  => 'Please select role.',
    ];
}
```

**Current Message**

> The role i d must be at least 1.

**Expected Message**

> Please select role.

Can you please guide me to right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public function messages () {
    return [
        'RoleID.min'  => 'Please select role.',
    ];
}
```